# How exactly does travelling to Bali work now?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, covid-19, bali

Good morning,

I am a bit confused about the most recent entry requirements for travelling to Bali. I was happy to read that they are finally open for international tourists again. But the whole quarantine, entry regulations, etc. seem a bit hard to get into for me at the moment. Does any one of you here happen to know more? Help would be highly appreciated as I plan to visit a friend as soon as possible.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indonesian travel regulations are convoluted and ever-changing, but as of February 2022, here's the rough process:

- Get vaccinated with 3 doses
- Apply for a B211A e-Visa
- Take a PCR test less than 48 hours before you arrive
- Book an approved hotel
- Take another PCR test on arrival
- <s>Quarantine at your hotel for 3 days.  You're *not* stuck in your room, meaning you can use the pool, beach etc, but you can't leave the hotel grounds.</s>
- Take yet another test on the 3rd day.
- Freedom!

Full details at [official government site indonesia.travel](https://www.indonesia.travel/gb/en/news/latest-travel-regulations-to-enter-bali), while bali.com has a [more digestible version](https://bali.com/bali/corona-virus-bali-indonesia/).

Also, all this assumes you can get a direct flight to Bali, but these are quite limited.  If you need to transit via Jakarta, things get even more complicated.

**Update**: One week has passed, and [Bali just dropped the quarantine-at-hotel requirement](https://milelion.com/2022/03/09/confirmed-bali-restarts-quarantine-free-travel-and-visa-on-arrival/).  Everything else including the 3 tests is still the same though, and apparently this is only possible if you travel *directly* to Bali, no transits via Jakarta etc allowed.